# Как реализовать сложение значений в Hash

Tags: ruby

Знакомлюсь с ruby, и возник вопрос, у меня есть hash. Как работать с таким видом `h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200, "c" => 300 }` я знаю. а как работать вот с таким

```
hash = {"One"=>[630.0, nil, 630.0, 0], 
 "Two"=>[630.0, 2.0, 630.0, 0], 
 "Three"=>[630.0, 5.0, 630.0, 0],
 "Four"=>[830.0, nil, 30.0, 0]}
```

И мне нужно сложить значение [1] всех ключей(Чтобы в итоге получилось 7.0). Как это реализовать?

Comment: А как бы вы это делали для "просто хэша"? Просто вы в шаге от решения, но пока непонятно, в каком именно.

Comment: Через each перебирая только ключи, each_value, ну и сложение

Comment: А что вам мешает внутри `each_value` просто брать не `значение`, а  `значение[1]`? И предвосхищая ответ "не работает" -- приведите в вопросе код, который не работает.

Answer (score 3):

```
My_hash.values.map{|i| i[1]}.compact.sum
```